# how to filter a extjs store with an exact match

Tags: extjs, filter, store, extjs4.1

I am using a filter for a store. The problem is that I want to return an exact match.

**For example:**

If I am filtering for `aa-1` in a grid it will show `aa-1` and `aa-1***` but if I want only see everything with `aa-1`.

I use this to filter:

```
listeners: {
    itemclick: function() {
        var data = grid.getSelectionModel().selected.items[0].data;
        store.clearFilter();
        store.filter('productsCat', data.productsCat);
    }
}
```

What do I have to do to do an exact match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regular expression in the filter to perhaps ensure that the comparison value was the end of the phrase.

Either that, or use the filterBy() method to define a comparison function, e.g.:

```
store.filterBy(this, function(rec, id) {
    if(rec.get('thefieldtocompare') === "what you want to compare against") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: what should 'this' be

Comment: 'this' is the scope that the function should execute in. I think looking at the latest docs the order of the function and context reference may be reversed. It's an optional property which defaults to the collection being filtered I believe.

Answer (score 14):

For ExtJS 4, you can simply use exactMatch and caseSensitive config options:

```
store.filter({
  property: fieldName,
  value: fieldValue,
  exactMatch: true,
  caseSensitive: true
})
```

Comment: This approach is the best

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention what version of ExtJS you are using but here are two general approaches:

1. Provide a regexp with exact mathing pattern:

   ```
   store.filter('productsCat', new RegExp('^' + Ext.escapeRe(data.productsCat) + '$'));
   ```

   or
2. Provide your own matching function to [filterBy](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy)

   ```
   store.filterBy(function(rec) {
       return rec.get('productsCat') === data.productsCat;
   });
   ```

Comment: sorry. I am using 4.1 I accept the answer but your answer is also working! Thanks