# Filter extjs Store by Exact Match

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this code to filter through my store

```
onLicenseGridSelect: function(rowmodel, record, index, eOpts) {
    Ext.getStore('LicenseFeaturesStore').clearFilter();
    Ext.getStore('LicenseFeaturesStore').filter( 'license_id', record.data.license_id );
},
```

It works fine however I need to search an exact value, instead of anyMatch values, right now it just returns values that match in any way, how can I change this to search an exact value.

So say I have array values (3, 35, 36)

and I run filter for 3, it gives me all those results, I just would want 3

Comment: should I post code on how the store and model looks?

Comment: What is your extjs version? This might be a duplicate check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984663/how-to-filter-a-extjs-store-with-an-exact-match

Comment: Ext JS 6.0.x i'll check link

Comment: Then you can use the `exactMatch` config .Api doc here https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.util.Filter-cfg-exactMatch

Answer (score 2):

This worked like a charm

```
var store = Ext.getStore('LicenseFeaturesStore');
store.filter({
    property: 'license_id',
    exactMatch: true,
    value: record.data.license_id
});
```

Perfect, thanks

Comment: so simple I dont know why I was struggling

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, hope it help!

```
var store = Ext.getStore('LicenseFeaturesStore');
var regEx = new RegExp('^' + 'ValueFilter' + '$');
store.filter('FilterColumn', regEx);
```

If you want filter exactly your value and one more empty row

```
 var regEx = new RegExp('^' + 'ValueFilter' + '$|^$');
```